# How to customize unidecode?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, unidecoder

I'm using `unidecode` module for replacing `utf-8` characters. However, there are some characters, for example greek letters and some symbols like `Å`, which I want to preserve. How can I achieve this?

For example,

```
from unidecode import unidecode
test_str = 'α, Å ©'
unidecode(test_str)
```

gives the output `a, A (c)`, while what I want is `α, Å (c)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run unidecode on each character individually. Have a whitelist set of characters that you use to bypass the unidecode.

```
>>> import string
>>> whitelist = set(string.printable + 'αÅ')
>>> test_str = 'α, Å ©'
>>> ''.join(ch if ch in whitelist else unidecode.unidecode(ch) for ch in test_str)
'α, Å (c)'
```